# Checksum on helm is different between Unix and windows

Tags: hash, kubernetes-helm

I’m using checksum annotation along with sha256sum function in order for the service to be rolled out if there is a configmap change in helm.
Recently I found out that there is a difference between the hash that is generated locally(windows) when I’m helm upgrading  to the hash  generated during the ci(Unix) when I’m helm upgrading, I have read a little a bit about it and found out that Unix and windows treat new lines differently , in windows it considers them as \r\n and in Unix it’s just \n

That’s the annotation i made

```
checksum/config: {{ tpl ($.Files.Get(printf “configs/%s/%s/application.yml” $.Values.env $serviceName)) $ | sha256sum }}
```

Is there a way of fixing that ?

Comment: It is typically the actual bytes in the file that is fundamental, especially for the purposes of a checksum computation.  What sequences of bytes are and are not considered to separate or terminate lines of text is a system-specific semantic interpretation.  If some of the files being included in the checksum need to conform to local text file conventions then you are probably out of luck -- such files must differ between Windows and Unix, and the checksums will then differ as well.

Answer (score 1):

On the Unix side running
`sed -i 's/\r$//' application.yml`
on the files in question will strip out the '\r', however I suspect you're wanting to get rid of the carriage return character on the Windows side before hashing the file. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct

Comment: Hmm. I might be a little out of my element, not being a Windows admin, nor a user of Kubernetes-Helm. Could you use the Windows Subsystem for Linux to run a shell script against the files in question? That way you could use `sed` to strip out the carriage returns. Kind of stabbing around here, but maybe this could be an avenue to check out. :-)

Comment: @john-bollinger makes a very good point. Thinking about this, you (maybe) could copy the file(s) to a temporary location, strip the '\r's from the file's line-ends, and checksum those just to have consistency in the hash values. Maybe then, I'm just over-thinking this...

Answer (score 0):

I endded up using unix2dos package btw

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).